# RecyclerView add Item, remove item what is the best solution?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm coming to a point, where I get a huge frustration.

RecyclerView is aweseom! I love to use it in my apps, but I'm facing with problems by deleting and adding items, updating list when removed or updated.

So I do have a recyclerview, where images are loaded with Picasso. I get the URL from my database.

Adding images are working, the problem is, notifyDataSetChanged when the Image is uploaded doesn't changed the view, even I put the position where it changed. I don't want to reload the Activity.

I tried following in the Activity:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Nothing happend.

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Nothing happend.

```
profilAdapterImages.notifyItemInserted(profilAdapterImages.getItemCount()+1);
```

Nothing happend

I wanted to try it **in** the adpater:

```
 public void update(List<getterImages> list){
    this.list.clear();
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Nothing is showing.

When I delete an Image, it gets deleted in the database.
In the database the urls are stored like this:

IMAGELINK

http://www.mysite.de/images/user/image123.png;http://www.mysite.de/images/user/image1234.png;http://www.mysite.de/images/user/image12345.png

E.g I delete the second image in the database it is this:

IMAGELINK

http://www.mysite.de/images/user/image123.png;http://www.mysite.de/images/user/image12345.png

My Problem is now, that the first image is showing but after the first
it is not loading. In my mind I have to make something with the list or adapter
but I have no clue.

So first I delete the url from the list.
    list.remove(position);

Then I delete the data from my database and the image from my webspace.

After that, only the first picutre is showing, the others are not loaded.

This is where the image will be deleted:

```js
   profilAdapterImages = new ProfilAdapterImages(list, Profil.this, new ImageSettingsCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSettings(final int position) {
                        final Dialog imageSettings = new Dialog(Profil.this);
                        imageSettings.setContentView(R.layout.edit_image);

                        Button buttonDeleteImage = imageSettings.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteImage);
                        Button buttonAddImage = imageSettings.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddImage);

                        buttonDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                updateData updateData = new updateData(Profil.this);

                                String[] filename = list.get(position).getImageURL().split("/");


                                Map<String,String> deleteFromServer = new HashMap<>();
                                deleteFromServer.put("mode","5");
                                deleteFromServer.put("username",USERNAME);
                                deleteFromServer.put("filename",filename[6]);
                                updateData.sendDataUpdate(deleteFromServer, new VolleyCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onUserExists(String[] result) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void OnSuccess() {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void OnError(String ErrorMessage) {

                                    }
                                });

                                list.remove(position);

                                List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
                                for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
                                    strings.add(list.get(i).getImageURL());
                                }
                                CharSequence[] cs = strings.toArray(new CharSequence[strings.size()]);

                                // Arrays.toString(cs).replace(",",";").replace("[","").replace("]","")



                                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("username",USERNAME);
                                map.put("mode","4");
                                map.put("row","IMAGELINK");
                                map.put("data",Arrays.toString(cs).replace(",",";").replace("[","").replace("]",""));
                                updateData.sendDataUpdate(map, new VolleyCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onUserExists(String[] result) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void OnSuccess() {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void OnError(String ErrorMessage) {

                                    }
                                });

                                imageSettings.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
```

And this is my Adapter:

```js
public class ProfilAdapterImages extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilAdapterImages.ViewHolder>{

    List<getterImages> list;
    Context context;
    ImageSettingsCallback imageSettingsCallback;

    public ProfilAdapterImages(List<getterImages> list, Context context, ImageSettingsCallback imageSettingsCallback) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageSettingsCallback = imageSettingsCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public ProfilAdapterImages.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProfilAdapterImages.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        getterImages getterImages = list.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context).load(getterImages.getImageURL()).resize(200,200).centerCrop().into(holder.blurImageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                holder.blurImageView.setBlur(20);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });

        Picasso.with(context).load(getterImages.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.preload).resize(200,200).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(),drawableToBitmap(holder.imageView.getDrawable()));
                roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });

        holder.imageButtonImageSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageSettingsCallback.onImageSettings(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        BlurImageView blurImageView;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton imageButtonImageSettings;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            blurImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSlider);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageButtonImageSettings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonImageSettings);
        }
    }

    public void update(List<getterImages> list){
        this.list.clear();
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

So guys, I would highly appreciate if you can help me with my problems.

Thanks and greetings from Germany.

Comment: post your code buddy.  this.list.clear();
    this.list = list; if you are doing this in activity and thinking it would reflect in the adatper then i am afraid it would not because list will point to new address. Post your code

Comment: Thank's buddy, added the code.